# Rails 5.2 Modal Not Opening

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

I have the following modal on my page that works perfectly:

```
<!-- New Topic Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="newTopicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="newTopicModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="newTopicModalLabel">Add a New Topic</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= render partial: "topics/js_form", locals: {topic: @new_topic } %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And is triggered by this:

```
      <p class="text-center">Select a topic to add below or <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newTopicModal">create a new topic</a>.</p>
```

However, when I copied it over and tried to do a second one for `projects`, the screen greys over but no modal appears.

The modal that does NOT work is this:

```
<!-- New Project Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="newProjectModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="newProjectModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="newProjectModalLabel">Add a New Project</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= render partial: "projects/js_form", locals: {project: @new_project } %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Triggered by this:

```
        <p class="text-center">Select a project to add this source to below or <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newProjectModal">create a new project</a>.</p>
```

I can't tell why the first one works and the second one doesn't.  Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: could you check browser console if there is any errors ?

Comment: @AhmedMagdy Nope, no console errors to be seen.

Comment: Try commenting out rails_ujs and restarting the server then uncommenting and restarting the server once again?

Comment: Could you inspection your page, and check if the modal element is in your Elements, and have a look of its styles(eg. display: block, display:none, height, width).